# Implementing getters for dynamically computed/transient state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm adopting React for future projects and generally enjoying it.

I have an architectural/design question regarding access to what I'll call "dynamic state properties."

Imagine a React component:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {device: {id: null}};
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to know whether my device is registered.

The obvious implementation, to me, is to add a getter to the component:

```js
get deviceRegistered() {
    return (this.state.device.id !== null);
}
```

But how would I access this down the component hierarchy?

React's architecture makes a lot of sense to me, but I'm struggling on this point.

I do *not* want to define my state as:

```js
this.state = {device: {id: null, registered: false}}
```

This smells bad, as whether the device is currently registered is, to me, an implementation detail that's a byproduct of the current state. Adding `registered` to state in this manner creates another property to maintain when we *should* be able to derive the value at any point anyway... but I just don't know quite how to.

I also don't want components down the tree to be doing this:

```js
if (this.props.deviceId !== null) {
    // do something, we have a device ID so we're registered
}
```

...because in the future, the criteria for a registered device might change.

So what's the "React way" to achieve this? I don't believe I can embed a getter directly into the state object literal without interfering with `setState(...)` object merges and I'm struggling to come up with an alternative solution which isn't a code smell and is readily accessible to components nested further down the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 'getters' in react.  There are 2 ways for child components to get the state of a parent component.  The first is to pass the state down to the child via props:

`<Child deviceId={this.state.device.id} />`

The second way would be to store the state in a global state manager.  The new Context API works great with the new hooks (which I'd highly recommend).  Or you can use something like redux to hold the global state.

Comment: So you're saying that, in this example, I should think less about making `registered` available globally, and instead compute it in `App` and pass it down the prop tree as required to children? That actually makes some sense now I stop to think about it; I wonder if I've been over-thinking a little.

Comment: Compute it as close to where it is used as possible.  It can be a big pain to pass props to child after child.  If you're going pretty deep into your tree w/ a prop it probably makes more sense to inject a global state manager like redux or the react Context.  But yes, passing down state to children is the standard way to share state between parents and children